# Trick to not show title bar in Edge Full Screen when moving the cursor past the top of the screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, microsoft-edge, fullscreen

This is probably a weird one, but here's my scenario:

I have a small monitor under my two primary monitors. On it, I keep a network dashboard in MS Edge full screen. You can see my screen layout below. The monitor in question is #4. The problem is, when I interact with the full-screen page and then move my cursor back to the monitor above, it triggers Edge's navigation to appear and it *does not go away*. The only work around I've found is to move another window to that screen, focus it, then drag it back up. This doesn't trigger the "hover" event.  This is less than ideal.

Any way to fix this or any other hacks that are less tedious?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need navigation, then you can try using the site as a [PWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/). This runs in its own window which can be fullscreened with F11. Hovering over the top of that window only creates a small X prompt, which fades out.

Just open your dashboard in Edge > `...` menu > Apps > "Install this site as an app". This creates a shortcut link that opens like below, and has some benefits like better caching:

```
msedge_proxy.exe --app-id=[long unique id] --app-url=https://my.dashboard.com/
```

---

Option two is to open the site as an "app", which is closer to a pop-up window. It still has a bar that shows up on mouseover in fullscreen, but it's very small. Just run or create a shortcut to:

```
msedge.exe --app=https://my.dashboard.com/
```

Comment: This is a great idea that I'm embarrassed I didn't think of! Oddly, the app behaves as expected in that if you move your mouse past the top of the screen the X appears and then goes away as it should.

Comment: Bah. Annoyingly, if you close the "app" and try to reopen it, I get a privacy error and when I click "Continue" it pops back into the browser tab :(

But this is still a great solution to my initial problem, so I'll leave it marked.